# Cesium - Placing billboards/map pins on polygons with extrudedHeight set

Tags: gis, cesiumjs

I have had a lot of difficulty trying to get a map pin to display consistently well on polygons that have their heights extruded. In my app, I am extruding heights of buildings based on an arbitrary value.

Later, upon selecting them, I add a billboard supplied with a custom image of a map pin.

```
//Get position of selected entity and add billboard at same position

var mPos = pCoords.positions[0];

var selectedPin = viewer.entities.add({

    name : 'selBoutique',
    position : mPos,
    billboard : {
        image : './img/marker.png',
        verticalOrigin : Cesium.VerticalOrigin.BOTTOM,
        eyeOffset: new Cesium.Cartesian3(0, 4, 0)
    }

});
```

I am setting the vertical origin to bottom, in order to keep its display consistent, and have been experimenting with offset in order to find a setting which works well for buildings of various heights in 3D view.

Are there any other factors I should be considering when trying to achieve a position for these pins which is never blocked by buildings of differing heights? I attempted to set the value of the offset dynamically based on the building's height. Perhaps I will play with this some more in the meantime.

Screenshots:

[image: angled view screenshot]

[image: top view screnshot]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: Certainly! Added.

Comment: In addition to `Cesium.VerticalOrigin.BOTTOM`, try modifying the pin's actual position by the height of the building.  Essentially, position the pin at the center of the roof of the building, not the ground floor of it.  Turn off the eyeoffset but keep the VerticalOrigin.Bottom.

Comment: You are the man! You've done it again. Thanks so much :) That was simpler than I thought. Please post an answer so I can mark it as correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the pin's actual position by the height of the building. Essentially, position the pin at the center of the roof of the building, not the ground floor of it. Then, turn off the `eyeOffset`, but keep your `VerticalOrigin.BOTTOM` setting.

Comment: This definitely answers the question. I did, however, have a subsequent issue, which may or may not be related, in that adding the billboard on top of my building causes the shape of the building to change. Specifically, a section of the polygon is cut out. With taller buildings, a building becomes taller and reshaped. Should I start a new question with some screenshot?

Comment: That sounds like [issue #2130](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/issues/2130).  If you're adventurous, try building the `billboard-transparency` branch and see if it works better.  There will be a slight performance hit for large numbers of pins, but it should fix the problem.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. This looks like a very similar issue. My client has chosen a different solution in the meantime, but I try to build that branch on my own time and report back my findings. Thanks again :)